# converting a list of strings into integers in python, skipping masked terms

Tags: python, numpy, integer, masking

Let's say I have a list of strings:

```
fnew:

masked_array(data = [-- -- '56527.9529' '56527.9544' '109.7147' '0.0089' '14.3638' '0.0779'
 '14.3136' '0.0775' '14.3305' '0.1049' '14.3628' '0.0837' '14.3628'
 '0.0837' '70.9990' '40.0050' '173.046' '-30.328' '73' '-99.175' '0.000'
 '0.000' '59.8' '0.0' '1.0'],

mask = [ True  True False False False False False False False False False False
 False False False False False False False False False False False False
 False False False],
       fill_value = N/A)
```

How do I get rid of the quotes from other elements, that is converting the other numbers into integer values so that I can do calculations with them?

Comment: It's hard to guess what your "list of strings" actually is from what you showed.  If you want help parsing a list of strings, showing `repr(your_list)` would be useful.  (It's also hard not to suspect there would be a much simpler way to serialize and unserialize the original numpy masked array.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> a = ['Foo', '59.8', 'bar', 'spam']
>>> arr = np.ma.array(a, mask=[True, False, True, True])
>>> arr.compressed().astype(float)
array([ 59.8])
>>> arr[arr.mask].data
array(['Foo', 'bar', 'spam'], 
      dtype='|S4')
```

Comment: I get an error that says cannot convert string to float! :(

Comment: @user3276219 Just saw your [comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22391462/converting-a-list-of-strings-into-integers-in-python-skipping-masked-terms/22391732#comment34042212_22391579) on other answer, try the updated solution.

Comment: Thankssss soooo much Ashwini! :D

Comment: how can I mask with a for loop? I have a giant masked array with 4000 lists that look like your list 'a' mentioned above, How can I do the np.ma.array command as a for loop for all the 4000 lines?

Comment: @AryaIyer You mean you've a list of lists?

Comment: yes, I have a huge list that is comprised of individual lists that look like your list 'a' above, and I'd like to do this in a for loop but I'm getting errors! :( sorry I'm new to python! and Thank you so much!!!

Comment: okay so I did a for loop to mask all the first and second elements of all lists by doing this: for i in range(len(big_list)):
...     big_list[i][0] = ma.masked
...     big_list[i][1] = ma.masked and this gives me big_list = [masked, masked, 'numbers', 'numbers']

Comment: then, I converted the entire big list with the first two elements that are now showing as 'masked' into a masked array by doing this: new_big_list = numpy.ma.array(big_list) which gives me new_big_list that looks like: [ '0.0', '0.0', 'numbers', 'numbers', 'numbers']

Comment: after this, if I follow what you said, and do this: unmasked = new_big_list.compressed().astype(float), then I get an error that says: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: could not convert string to float: random words from first element

Answer (score 0):

Probably something with zip. You data structure is not very clear, but :

```
[int(float(val)) for val, maskVal in zip(masked_array, mask) if maskVal]
```

should be close enought.

Comment: well it's just a list of strings, that looks like ['words', 'wordsnumber', 'number', 'number', 'number'] so I basically masked the first two elements since they aren't numbers, and now i want to convert the rest into integers so I can do calculations with these lists

Answer (score 0):

This is exactly what [`itertools.compress`](http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/itertools.html#itertools.compress) is for:

```
from itertools import compress

array_o_nums = map(lambda x: int(float(x)), itertools.compress(data, mask))
```

(As the strings actually represent floats rather than integers, they have to be converted to floats first.)

Comment: it doesn't work! I'm having an error it doesn't recognize the mask at the end!